# How to pass params from a stack navigator to a Material top tab navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a Stack named as **PaymentStack** which consists of two **Stack screens**. The second screen consists of a **MaterialTopTabs** which have two other Screens named as 'Net banking' and 'Cash Payment'.

**PaymentStack** consists of two screens, one screen is a simple **Stack screen** navigator with a functional component passed in the **component** attribute of **Stack.Screen** but for the other screen I have tried to make a **Material Top tabs Navigator**

```
const TopTabStack = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

//this MaterialTopTab is passed as a component in the below PaymentStack tab navigator
const MaterialTopTab = ({ navigation }) => (
    <TopTabStack.Navigator>
        <TopTabStack.Screen
            name={'Net banking'}
            component={ComponentX} //*I want to receive the params in this screen/cmpnt.
        />
        <TopTabStack.Screen
            name={'Cash payment'}
            component={ComponentX}
        />
    </TopTabStack.Navigator>
) 

//this PaymentStack is passed as a component in Bottom tab navigator
const PaymentStack = ({navigation}) => {
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
            name={'PaymentOption'}
            component={ComponentY} //Suppose I am on this Screen
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name={'MaterialTopTab'}
            component={MaterialTopTab} //this component is defined above
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
}

export default function AppStack = () => {
   return (
    <NavigationContainer>
       <PaymentStack /> //defined above
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Now suppose I am in the screen named **PaymentOption** whose component is **ComponentY** and I want to navigate to the Screen named as **Material top tab** whose component is a **Material top tab navigator** in which two screens are present named as **Net banking** and **Cash payment** and receive the params in the **Net banking**. How can we do this ?

I tried

```
navigation.navigate('MaterialTopTab', {body : data} )
```

But when I am accessing the body in ComponentX , it shows undefined.

```
function ComponentX({route}){
   console.log(route.params.body)
   .......
   .......
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be accessing `route.params` in the `<MaterialTopTab />` component instead? Since that's where you're passing it to

Comment: Ok, But MaterialTopTab is a Tab navigator, how am I supposed to access from it and then pass it to one of its screen names as 'Net banking'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, hopefully this is what you're looking for. Please ignore the typescript typings if you aren't using Typescript. As you can see, our `RootStack` component is a stack navigator that contains 1 screen and a `TabNavigator`. I don't have experience using top tabs but I'm pretty sure it works the same way as bottom tabs. We can navigate to our `TabNavigator` from the first screen in `RootStack` (`Screen1`), passing a prop called `helloKitty` to the `TabNavigator`. The `TabNavigator` then passes the `helloKitty` prop from `route.params` to the first screen in the `TabNavigator` (`TabScreen1`). I'm not particularly sure if what I did with `TabScreen1Props` is the proper way to do it, but it works for now. Honestly though, at this point, if this is what your navigation structure looks like, why not consider `useContext` or a state management library like `Zustand`?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { createStackNavigator, StackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { BottomTabScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import { Button } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'

type HelloKittyType = string
type RootStackParamList = {
  Screen1: undefined
  SomeCuteTabs: { helloKitty: HelloKittyType }
}
type RootStackNavigationProps = StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>
type SomeCuteTabsParamList = {
  TabScreen1: undefined
  TabScreen2: undefined
}
type SomeCuteTabsNavigationProps = BottomTabScreenProps<SomeCuteTabsParamList>

const RootStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>()
const SomeCuteTabs = createStackNavigator<SomeCuteTabsParamList>()

const Screen1 = ({ navigation }: RootStackNavigationProps) => (
  <View>
    <Button title="Go to tabs" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SomeCuteTabs', { helloKitty: 'I love hello kitties' })} />
  </View>
)

interface TabScreen1Props extends SomeCuteTabsNavigationProps {
  helloKitty: HelloKittyType | undefined
}
const TabScreen1 = ({ route, navigation, helloKitty }: TabScreen1Props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(helloKitty)
  }, [])
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Tab Screen 1</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
const TabScreen2 = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Tab Screen 1</Text>
  </View>
)

const RootStackComponent = () => (
  <RootStack.Navigator>
    <RootStack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
    <RootStack.Screen name="SomeCuteTabs" component={SomeCuteTabsComponent} />
  </RootStack.Navigator>
)

const SomeCuteTabsComponent = ({ route, navigation }: RootStackNavigationProps) => (
  <SomeCuteTabs.Navigator>
    <SomeCuteTabs.Screen name="TabScreen1">{(props) => <TabScreen1 {...props} helloKitty={route.params?.helloKitty} />}</SomeCuteTabs.Screen>
    <SomeCuteTabs.Screen name="TabScreen2" component={TabScreen2} />
  </SomeCuteTabs.Navigator>
)

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStackComponent />
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try, thanks for answering! And could you also provide some resources to use navigation with useContexf?

Comment: @Madhavmishra `react-navigation` is on v6 already, but this should still help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62242973/how-to-use-context-api-in-react-navigation-5 But personally, I would go with `zustand` for its simplicity and ease of use in projects of any size, and unless you like writing lots of code, probably `redux-toolkit` (RTK) for very large projects